# R - pca axis lines

Tags: r, pca, axes

I'm trying to figure out why my pca axes lines are not showing up in my final pca plot [pca plot with no axes lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YKo6.png) but nothing is standing out. I've tried going through and commenting out parts of the code but that hasn't helped. Any help is appreciated!

Data: https://pastebin.com/MWNfUz3S

```
#not all of these are used for the pca portion of my code but all are used at some point
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)
library(gtable)
library(ggfortify)
library(data.table)
library(vegan)
library(ggrepel)
library(forcats)
library(scales)


input <-"End Members 2020_03.xls"
mydata<-read_excel(input,sheet=1)
rm(input)

df<-mydata[,c(5:24)]
pca<-rda(df,scale=T) #Conducting a correlation PCA
#Percent variance explained by PCs
pervar<-round(pca$CA$eig/sum(pca$CA$eig)*100,2)
#Plot values and limits for all LOP plots
scrs<-scores(pca,display=c("sites","species"))
xlim<-with(scrs,range(species[,1],sites[,1]))*1.1
ylim<-with(scrs,range(species[,2],sites[,2]))*1.1
ordlab<-ordipointlabel(pca,display="species")$labels

factor.scores<-as.data.frame(pca$CA$v) %>% select(PC1,PC2) %>% mutate(variable=row.names(.),PC1=PC1)
factor.scores.alt<-as.data.frame(scrs$species)
site.scores<-as.data.frame((pca$CA$u)) %>% select(PC1,PC2)

pca.scores<-as.data.frame(scrs$sites)
mydata$PC1<-pca.scores$PC1
mydata$PC2<-pca.scores$PC2

#Generate better labels in PCA plot
variables<-factor.scores.alt %>% mutate(PC1.adj=PC1*1.7,PC2.adj=PC2*1.7,labels=rownames(factor.scores.alt))

landuse.color.and.season.shape.pca<-ggplot(mydata,aes(PC1,PC2))+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0.0)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.0)+
  #geom_point(aes(shape=Season,color=reorder(Landuse,Classification)),size=2)+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Season,color=Landuse),size=3)+
  geom_text_repel(data=variables,aes(PC1.adj,PC2.adj,label=labels),size=3,fontface="plain",family="serif")+
  scale_color_gdocs(name="Landuse")+
  #scale_shape_discrete(solid=T,name="Seasons")+
  xlim(-3,3)+
  ylim(3,-3)+
  xlab("PC1 [56.4%]")+
  ylab("PC2 [20.2%]")+
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10,face="plain",family="serif"),
        legend.title=element_text(size=10,face="plain",family="serif"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10,face="plain",family="serif"),
        axis.text=element_text(size=10,face="plain",family="serif"),
        plot.background=element_blank())

pca.legend<-get_legend(landuse.color.and.season.shape.pca + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8),
                                                                  legend.title=element_text(size=10),
                                                                  text=element_text(family="serif"),
                                                                  legend.position="bottom",
                                                                  legend.title.align=0.5,
                                                                  legend.box="horizontal",
                                                                  legend.box.just="top",
                                                                  legend.background=element_rect(fill="white",colour=F)))

pca.plot.final<-plot_grid(pca.legend,
                          landuse.color.and.season.shape.pca + theme(legend.position="none",
                                                                     panel.background=element_blank()),
                          nrow=2,rel_heights=c(0.1,1.1))

pca.plot.final
```

This part of the post does not actually relate to the question but rather is being used to allow this post to be accepted. Apparently if you need to include more details with more the more code you provide. I don't really have any more details to add so here we are... Hope everyone is doing well.

Comment: can you explain who do you mean by "my pca axes lines are not showing up" ?

Comment: Basically I want to have lines that represent the PC1 and PC2 axes, similar to the pca presented here (https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Principal-component-analysis-PCA-graph-combining-score-plot-samples-and-loadings_fig5_325746941). Currently there are no lines showing up, just the score labels.

Comment: I've also used this code before to create other PCAs and I've never ran into this problem for them.

Comment: oh it's a biplot you want errr.. you did not input the vectors, how are they supposed to appear? ok i am totally ignorant, but where in the code above did you pull out the eignevectors?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, but I don't pull out the eigenvectors here. I was thinking since it was a correlation pca, the eigenvectors would not be needed to plot the PCA. Should they be included and do you have any suggestions on how I could incorporate it into the code?